# SDWebImage Demo fails out of hte box on Xcode5 with error: Apple LLVM 5.1 Error

Tags: ios, image, caching, xcode5, sdwebimage

Has anyone experienced and fixed this problem? I am trying to try out SDWebImage. But when I try to run their demo, it keeps crashing. I am using XCode5. Should I be downloading a specific version of the project to test? If so which one? My XCode version is 5.1.1

Comment: Haven't tried out their demo, but I would highly recommend it - I've used in a few apps and it's great. I might recommend just dropping the relevant files into your project and test it out there.

Comment: Actually I wanted to try it out so I could help answer a question here. So I hadn't built anything yet to try out. But I just put together my own mini project and it works fine with it. I haven't found any hiccups yet. I cannot say there isn't any (too soon); but I haven't found them. So thanks for the heads up. The demo was the issue indeed.